# Problema para hacer un JOIN entre tablas encadenadas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
processes:
id
name

dependencies
id
name
process_id

types_assets:
id
name

assets:
id
name
state
dependency_id
types_asset_id
```

Necesito hacer una consulta en donde se relacionen las 4 tablas, la tabla principal de assets, pero no se como hacer un join entre la tabla process ya que esta tabla no se relaciona directamente y necesito visualizar el nombre del process que está relacionado con la dependency a la que pertenece el asset.

Trate de hacerlo usando directamente una sql cruda con DB pero el problema es que me devuelve un array y no un objeto y me genera otro tipo de problemas con la paginación.

La consulta cruda es esta (si funciona así):

```
SELECT a.id AS id,a.name AS name,a.state AS state,d.name AS dependency,t.name AS type,p.name AS process
FROM assets as a, dependencies AS d, types_assets as t, processes as p
WHERE
a.dependency_id = d.id AND
a.types_asset_id = t.id AND
d.process_id = p.id
```

También trate de usar JOIN pero como la tabla process no se relaciona directamente con assets no me funciona.

Otra forma que me funcionó fue usar with, el problema es que quiero dar al usuario la posibilidad de dar orden asendente o descendente en la visualización de datos pero con with se me dificulta mucho decirle cual es el campo de ordenación. Me podrían ayudar por favor, llevo estancado en esto mucho tiempo.

Comment: Hacen falta detalles tales como: ¿qué resultado exacto esperas?, ¿tienes los modelos y las relaciones definidas?, ¿qué has intentado desde Eloquent y qué resultado te da?

Comment: Hola, el resultado esperado es el mismo del sql, es decir, a.id,a.name,a.state,d.name,t.name,p.name, pero como decía en el post, solo logro tener el resultado con la sql cruda y me devuelve un array no un objeto

Comment: Intenta hacer los modelos, declarar las relaciones y pasar está query que ya tienes y a partir de eso te ayudamos